# Gnome-Terminal stretch background image to fit window size

Tags: gnome-terminal, desktop-background

Is there a way to stretch the selected image in my gnome terminal to fit the current window size?

Using
gnome-session 3.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there is a specific option to fit the image according to the window size.

The only options supported by gnome-terminal to modify the background are listed below:

```
$ gconftool-2 --recursive-list /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default | grep background
scroll_background = false
background_darkness = 0.58315799999999995
background_image = /usr/share/backgrounds/Forever_by_Shady_S.jpg
background_color = #000000000000
background_type = image
```

When I set `/usr/share/backgrounds/Forever_by_Shady_S.jpg` I get the following gnome-terminal window:

[image]

In order to have a background image automatically resized/adjusted to your terminal window size you could try [`urxvt`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man7/urxvt.7.html):

```
sudo apt-get install rxvt-unicode
```

and run your terminal this way:

```
urxvt -pixmap /usr/share/backgrounds/Forever_by_Shady_S.jpg -fg white
```

The result will automatically resize the background image when you resize the window:

[image]